How deep should a plumbing thermowell be into the flow?
I want to add a thermometer to a section of 1" copper residential DHW. This connection will not be at an elbow, it will be along a linear section.
I think I'll add a tee so I can thread in a thermometer. Probes come in many lengths. How far into the pipe should the thermowell go?

I'd strongly suggest that you skip adding multiple potential leaks and use a clip-on pipe thermometer (measures at the surface of the pipe) instead.
No new fittings, so no added leak potential; no restriction in the flow.
Rather than measuring through the thickness of a thermowwell, you're measuring through the pipe wall. The difference in those two is miniscule in domestic pipe sizes. There isn't a huge temperature gradient between the center of flow and the pipe wall, as a practical matter.

Sufficiently deep so water flows around it well, also make sure the sensor contacts the thermowell properly.
